# New domains and aliases in Virtual Hosts not working

Tags: virtualhost, apache-2.4, ubuntu-14.04

We have a new Ubuntu VPS and have a couple of sites hosted fine on it. We've added a new one, yet the www of the domain isn't working. We've swapped them around (so it's the server name and not the alias etc), added a wildcard alias, it just keeps going to the default site.

Our conf file for it looks like the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.domain.co.uk
        ServerAlias domain.co.uk *.domain.co.uk

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.co.uk/htdocs/
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog /var/www/domain.co.uk/error.log
        CustomLog /var/www/domain.co.uk/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

It's weird because one of our other sites, which we copied the conf from, has both a working www. and non www. So we changed that, created a new sub domain on our dev domain name, and added it to the working conf, and it didn't work either. Any help would be grand!

Answer (score 0):

I feel super dumb now, but I believe we weren't doing **sudo** service apache2 reload. Although why it gives you no error that you have used sudo is beyond me.